# Does the apply_async method always allocate processes as they become available?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, pool

I'm using python's multiprocessing module some analyses. Specifically, I use a pool and the `apply_async` method to compute some results from a large number of variables. The time required to compute the results vary drastically with the input, which got me wondering if the pool will either A) immediately assign a process to each input when I call `apply_async`, or if B) processes are assigned as they become ready. My worry is A) would imply that one of the pool's processes might be assigned to several of the 'heavy' inputs and so take longer than necessary to complete.

I tried running the below code and got similar returns in each run (<2 seconds), indicating that B) is the case, at least here. Is that what should be expected to happen always?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time

def foo(x):
    if x % 4 == 0:
        time.sleep(1)  # Simulating a large workload
    else:
        time.sleep(.1)  # Simulating a small workload

    return 2*x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(20):
        with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
            jobs = []
            now = time.time()
            vals = list(range(1, 9))
            np.random.shuffle(vals)
            for x in vals:
                jobs.append(pool.apply_async(foo, args=(x,)))
            results = [j.get() for j in jobs]
            elapsed = time.time() - now

        print(elapsed)
```